# Limitation of Android Graphics

Tags: java, android, animation, graphics

Please have a look at the following image, it is a black and white print of a colour photo.

[image]

This is a Fuel level indicator. User click on the up-down arrows and the fuel bar goes up-down. I have never done graphics like this before, and since this is a for a office software, I have no idea what kind of library can do this.

There is one other image.

[image]
This is your Car Dashboard Mileage meter. You can click in this and type the value and the numbers in the image will count down/ count up for the typed value.

You are not creating a Game here and therefore, can you create something like this in Android?

Comment: @HarishTalanki: what????????

Comment: @HarishTalanki: I can see.

Comment: I not understand what is the problem. when the user click up fill the retcengle (or put while rectangle image over old one) or when the user click down put black rectagle... (you not need here speical grapichs..)

Comment: I am sorry, but even now I am not able to see the image. I am not sure about the reason.

Comment: @HarishTalanki: Any issue in your PC? Seems like others can see!

Answer (score 1):

It's doable by creating a custom `View`. You can use Canvas to draw anything you want. But in this case you can instead extend `ViewGroup` class and draw by yourself only "non-standard" parts. (for example, you can reuse standard buttons by adding them to your `ViewGroup` subclass.)
More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

Comment: The same principle applies here. You use standard classes for what they can do, and do your custom drawing for anything else... Also don't forget to search the web - many custom view classes are already done by others.
You can also use OpenGL to accelerate drawing, but I don't think it will improve drawing in this case.